# How can I video chatting on android using webrtc with usb camera?

Tags: android, webrtc, libjingle

I have implemented WebRTC using libjingle on Android.
And I have tested it between android devices and web browsers.
It works well.

But I will use a USB camera on an android device.
Now, it fails to connect to the USB camera on libjingle.
How can I implement WebRTC on an android device with a USB Camera?
Have you any idea about this problem?

Comment: The issue is that when you try to create a similar class like **VideoCapturerAndruav** you find that there are internal classes that you need and cannot access because they are internal classes such as **SurfaceTextureHelper** and **VideoCapturerAndroid.CapturerObserver**

I guess the key is to recompile the webrtc library and exposes those classes.